# Align windows to a grid in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, window-manager, alignment

I've become so used to aligning windows to a grid on Windows (via Win+Arrow Key) and Linux (via Compiz Grid) that when I sit down at a Mac I want to gouge my eyes out trying to align windows.

How can I align windows to a grid in Mac OS X? Do I need to install an application?

Here is an [example of Compiz Grid plugin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHMKhiZmlV0&hd=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, kind of, Optimal Layout, an app I developed offers a way for you to rearrange a group of windows into a few different grid layouts.

Check it out:
http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/

Answer (score 5):

[Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/) is another simple tool for managing window layout on Mac OS X.  They have a video demonstrating how it works, it's pretty intuitive once you see it once.

Answer (score 3):

- [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=1722) has Aero Snap like functionality (good if you like mouse gestures).
- [SizeUp](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) has a few more options (good if you like keyboard shortcuts).

Comment: BetterTouchTool is the only completely free option I could find. Thanks for recommendation. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

## No.

I would read [Using Expose Effectively](http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/using-expose-effectively/). While not the same as the grid layout, it can be used very effectively.

Comment: Exposé has nothing on a grid layout. I've been using all 3 platforms for more than 3 years and I find Macs to be the most lacking :-/

Comment: I didn't say it was the same, I said it can be used effectively.

Comment: I don't think that this is really an efficiency thing. I think it's probably an aesthetic thing for the OP...